# How do I convert an object using ObjectMapper and inject dependencies into it

Tags: java, spring, jackson

I am trying to convert Object to a concrete class using jackson ObjectMapper and to inject dependencies after I convert it.Here is the example:

```
public class SimpleClass{
    private String parameter;
    @JsonIgnore
    private SomeService service;

    /** getters and setters **/
    public void doSomethingFromService(){
        //call some methods from the service
    }
}
```

After attempt to deserialize the object(value is map containing parameters) :

```
ObjectMapper om = new ObjectMapper();
om.convertValue(value,SimpleClass.class).doSomethingFromService();
```

-> result to a NullPointerException...
How to inject the service?

Can I get the service from the context and inject it by default constructor?

Comment: Jackson is JSON/XML De/Serialization framework, not CDI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you want some kind of auto-wiring in your `SimpleClass` bean,
you need to annotate its property `SomeService service` with `@Autowired`.

```
public class SimpleClass {

    private String parameter;

    @JsonIgnore
    @Autowired
    private SomeService service;

    // getter and setter for parameter (omitted here for brevity)

    public void doSomethingFromService(){
        //call some methods from the service
    }
}
```

As others already said, `ObjectMapper` does not do any dependency injection.
But you can combine the `@Autowired`-ignoring `ObjectMapper`
with some manually triggered auto-wiring.

For that you need an [`AutowireCapableBeanFactory`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/config/AutowireCapableBeanFactory.html) which you get by Spring's
normal dependency injection with `@Autowired`.
Then you use its [`autowireBean(Object)`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/config/AutowireCapableBeanFactory.html#autowireBean-java.lang.Object-) method
to inject the bean's `@Autowired` properties.

```
@Autowired
private  AutowireCapableBeanFactory autowireCapableBeanFactory;

public void doSomething(Map<String, Object> value) throws Exception {
    ObjectMapper om = new ObjectMapper();
    SimpleClass bean = om.convertValue(value, SimpleClass.class);
    autowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireBean(bean);
    bean.doSomethingFromService();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you were doing the initialization of the `SimpleClass` object yourself then you can make it work by autowiring the paritcular instance with [AutowireCapableBeanFactory](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/config/AutowireCapableBeanFactory.html) in that case the `@Autowrire` of the service will work since Spring manages also the partical instance of the `SomeClass` object.

That said, it is not the way to go. Data objects should be isolated from the business logic.

Back to your case, you can't autowire even in the way I mentined because Jackson is the provider of the instance, and Jackson **requires** the presence of empty constructor.

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible. Only objects that have been instanciated with spring can use @Autowired.

It's simple : when you annotate an object with @Service, spring will try to resolve all it's dependency with introspection.

With jackson (or if you try to instanciate an object by yourself) you are totally out of the scope of spring.

And I should had, what you are trying to do (even if it was possible) is not a good practice. You should'n mix your data objects with business processing.

Comment: I understand that, but can i inject it in the default constructor for example ?It is not mandatory to use autowired annotation to inject a bean.

Comment: @xyz Not possible since Jackson **needs** the empty constructor.

Comment: You can always add setter for your service. But why would you do that ?
You are not supposed to receive this kind of objects from the outside of your app.

Comment: for example if the service validate the dto

Comment: If the service only validates the dto, you could use pure functions instead of using a service (or use validation libraries already integrated on spring and jax-rs, like hibernate-validator).

Answer (score -1):

Injection of services is only possible with a framework like Spring, as said previously.

If you are using Spring, annotate your service class with @Service and then as opposed to using @Autowired declare your service private final and inject it using a constructor (IMO I find this works better).

If you aren't using Spring, you'll need to new up an instance of the service and then call that instance - unless of course it's a static...

Comment: Jackson requires empty constructors.